# MacOS Strange Terminal Prompt, Tried Resetting Terminal

Tags: git, macos, terminal

[Link to picture of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QggoJ.jpg)

```
Last login: Mon Feb 27 14:57:49 on ttys000
engr2-2-79-41-dhcp:~ <censored>$
```

Depending on what network I am connected to, my terminal lists odd things on every line such as "engr2-....". I accidentally did something that created this problem. Once it started occurring, git commands stopped working. I tried to delete configuration files for the terminal, but it only reset the theme of my terminal.

Comment: Have you made any changes to bash profile. (i.e. .bashrc or .bash_profile), where tried to change prompt with `PS1`?

Comment: That text is your computer's hostname. This behavior is normal.

Answer (score 9):

What you're seeing is normal, just a bit confusing. It's the computer's hostname. The standard prompt includes it in an attempt to be helpful.

In the unix command-line interface, it's normal to switch to other directories (with `cd`), other user accounts (with `su` or `sudo`), and even other computers (with `ssh`). Keeping track of where you are can get confusing, so the standard shell prompt includes where and who you are (the computer's hostname, current username, and current directory); sort of the command-line equivalent of a GPS system.

The problem is that the way it determines the computer's hostname sometimes causes more confusion than anything else. The process goes a bit like this:

Bash shell: I need to include the hostname in the command prompt. "Hey, operating system: what's the hostname of this computer we're on?"

OS: My hostname? Gosh, I wonder what that is. I know, I'll ask the DNS (domain name service) server if it has a name for my IP address. "Hey, DNS, what's the name associated with 2.2.79.41?"

DNS server: 2.2.79.41? That doesn't really have a specific name, it's just part of the pool of addresses the DHCP server hands out to computers that connect to the engineering network. Oooh, I know, I'll call it engr2-2-79-41-dhcp. It's better than nothing, right?"

(There's a variant of this where the DNS server has a note that, three years ago, the DHCP server handed that IP address to something that gave its name as "Fred's Android phone", and it assumes that same device must surely still be there, so it uses freds-android-phone.lan or something similar.)

...so the DNS sends that name to the OS, which passes it to the shell, which displays it in your prompt, which causes you to say "WTF is that????".

Keep in mind here: every part of this process is something trying to do the best it can to provide the best information it can. Nothing is actually wrong, it's just rather confusing if you don't know what it's doing or why.

Which brings me to your problem with git commands: this is not causing it. It is almost certainly not related to it. Ignore the weird prompt, and troubleshoot your git setup.

Comment: which DNS does it use

Comment: @minseong Whatever's configured in the Network Preferences, which usually means it's whatever your Mac got from the DHCP server on the local network. In the common small office/home setup, it'll be the local network router acting as both DHCP and DNS server.

Comment: Doesn't this suggest that the hostname changes when you change networks? Someone commented on apple.SE that the hostname doesn't change https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358605/my-hostname-is-not-my-laptop-name/358611#comment473533_358605

Comment: so there is no solution to it? I forced shutdown terminal and restarted and the name was gone. Is that normal?

Comment: @user0193 Whether that's normal normal depends on your network setup. If you really want to "solve" it (and again, it's not really a problem, just confusing), you can override the hostname with `sudo scutil --set HostName nameyouwanttouse` (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal)).