# how did the format of my bash terminal change?

Tags: bash

I am a beginner with command line and bash.  I am on a Mac with High Sierra 10.13.  Recently the format of my bash terminal has changed.  Previously it would display my computer name but now it says `192:[working directory] [user]$`
Where did this `192` come from?

I think that this may have occurred after I installed homebrew but I am not sure.

I have looked at `~/.bash_profile` and I do not see any PS1 variable.

All the functionality appears to be the same, but I preferred the previous formatting.  What did I do to change this and how can I change it back?

Comment: What does `hostname` output?

Comment: What if you `echo $PS1` or `$PROMPT`?

Comment: ```192:~ devin$ hostname
192.168.15.102

192:~ devin$ echo $PS1
\h:\W \u\$

192:~ devin$ echo $PROMPT

192:~ devin$ ```

Comment: Sounds like the usual hostname confusion. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/346701/mac-os-x-terminal-where-does-the-prompt-name-come-from), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/357159/osx-terminal-showing-incorrect-hostname), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal), etc.

Comment: so did the hostname change?

Comment: Yes, but it's not a meaningful change, just confusing. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal/42498088#42498088).

Comment: Thank you everyone.  My searches were yielding nothing without knowing the word **hostname**.  Thanks for the links Gordon

Comment: BTW, in general, StackOverflow's scope is *writing software*. Thus, questions about writing shell scripts are on-topic, but questions about using bash as an end-user are not; for those, see [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Good to know @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

The change in "format" was due to a change in the `hostname`. 
The reason for this is explained by Gordon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal/42498088#42498088)