# What is this operation system

Tags: macos, security

I think my macbook is compromised. In my terminal when I type uname -a 
i get this 
Darwin mMaxys-iPhone 18.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Mon Nov 12 20:24:46 PST 2018; root:xnu-4903.231.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_6

I don't recognize this operating system
my mac os is macOS Mojave 10.14.2 (18C54)

Comment: Okay I have checked Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0 is a recognized kernal. What throw me off is the iPhone part

Comment: It's most likely that the IP address your MacBook is now using was previously used by someone's iPhone, and it registered that name with your local DNS server, and so now whatever computer's on that IP address is known as "mMaxys-iPhone" whether or not that's really an appropriate name for it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal) for an explanation of a similar problem.

Comment: thanks man @GordonDavisson. This was my first time experiencing this issue

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways to see your MacOS version inside the command terminal.
1. Try using system profiler `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType` this will give you output as under:
[using system profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFeXK.png)

2. Or use this command `sw_vers` it refers to software version

[sw_vers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9olSr.png)