# Weird Termimal Prompt Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

I did an update to Mojave and now when I go to the terminal is says:
csarson:~ janet$

it never had the **csarson:~** part before.  I checked and there is no user with this name.  Is it something I should be concerned with?  Does anyone know if it a bash profile of some kind?

Thanks in advance,
Janet

Comment: You can check the output of `echo "$PS1"` to see your prompt variable, and then check the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) to see what the different parts mean.

Comment: "csarson" is probably another computer that happened to be using the same IP address your computer is now using, and the name "stuck". It's not actually a problem, just a bit confusing. See: [MacOS Strange Terminal Prompt, Tried Resetting Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is the name of your computer. The terminal prompt format is:

```
Computer-Name:{working-directory} {username}$
```

So in this case `csarson` is your computer's name. See the image below for how it looks on my MacBook Pro, also running Mojave.

[image]