# what is this after my username on mac terminal? username@xks12asd8m3

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal, operating-system

My mac os terminal shows username and some alphanumeric text after the [at] symbol. I want to know what it stands for? And what is it called? 
For e.g. in username@xks12asd8m3 what does xks12asd8m3 stand for?

Comment: likely the hostname... is it your mac or a shared school/work system?

Comment: You can look at the contents of the `PS1` variable and check the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) for the meaning of the different characters.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal), and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/357159/osx-terminal-showing-incorrect-hostname).

Answer (score 0):

This is the hostname of the machine to which "username" is logged in via the current terminal session.