# Weird combination of numbers and letters in front of terminal prompt macOS

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, virtualenv, python-venv

Curious as to why I have the sequence : `h-63-4` in front of my terminal prompt.

Example: `(base) h-63-4:~ axel$`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmo82.png)

I believe I was messing around with virtual environments in python when it first started appearing, but haven't been able to figure out as to what's causing it.

Contents of my .bashrc:

```
   # System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"
```

Comment: [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), read about prompting and the special characters in `PS1`, esp. `\h` and `\W`

Comment: That's your computer's name. Verify with the `hostname` command.

Comment: The prompt you show is not what's set in `.bashrc` – are you running zsh? What's the output of `echo "$PS1"`?

Comment: Is that a hostname coming from reverse DNS? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal/).