# Mac Terminal symbol break down

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, command-line-arguments

I just opened my terminal to find someone random's iPhone name after the @ sign

> oliviaporter@Maxs-Iphone ~ %

I realized that this A - isn't an immediate issue as it looks like there are a lot of solutions to resetting the host name and B - that I don't actually know what the symbols mean. So my first questions are what is the @ sign telling us? what is the ~ and the % sign telling us? My second question is how did this get connected to "maxs Iphone" in the first place?

And if there is too simple of a question, can someone point me in the direction of documentation?

Comment: The format is "<username>@<hostname> <current directory> %". It's getting the hostname from the local DNS server, which probably remembers a previous device (apparently Max's phone) that was at the same IP address. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal/42498088#42498088). BTW, Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [Superuser](https://superuser.com) and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) are better places to ask about things like this.

Comment: thank you @GordonDavisson I will look to those sites next time. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the traditional shell prompt.

It shows `$USER@$HOSTNAME`, where the `@` separates the user name from the hostname. It is followed by your current directory, and in this case, it uses the `~` shortcut for your $HOME directory. You can also show it with the `pwd` (Print Working Directory) command or with the `$PWD` variable (try `echo $PWD`).

The `%` at the end is the traditional `zsh` prompt. (Bash generally uses `$` or `#` if you are logged in as root).